# Get the coordinates of dominant colours from UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, pixel

I'm not able to find the coordinates from UIImageView possessing dominant colours. This is the code:

```
for yCo in 0 ..< Int(imageView.frame.height) {
    for xCo in 0 ..< Int(imageView.frame.width) where image.getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x: xCo, y: yCo)) == dominantColorFirst {
        print(CGPoint(x: xCo, y: yCo)) // uses 99% CPU -> Leads to hang app
    }
}
extension UIImage {

func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor { // get pixel color

let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)}
```

Due to large no. of iterations, Im not able to find out the coordinates. It uses more memory and hangs the app, Is there any other way to work around?

Answer (score 0):

I did a image process project before. I get alpha of all pixel and cache it. (my image only 1200x1200px)

Don't know why but when I using `print` on the for loop, it take too much memory and delay the app.

I must walk around with

```
var cachePointArray = [CGPoint]()
for yCo in 0 ..< Int(imageView.frame.height) {
    for xCo in 0 ..< Int(imageView.frame.width) {
        let point = CGPoint(x: xCo, y: yCo)
        if image.getPixelColor(pos: point) == dominantColorFirst {
            cachePointArray.append(point)
        }
    }
}
print(cachePointArray)
```

and in run much faster

You can try this for test

(Sorry I dont enough point to comment, if it doesn't help, ignore it)

Comment: Yes, but I dont put the `print` into the for-loop. The `print` on for-loop take too much time

Comment: Still taking a lot of time and doesn't reach under the if condition.